# TypeError: $navigation.find(...).tab is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using jquery.bootstrap.wizard to implement paper-bootstrap-wizard, I don't know why am getting the below issue.

```
TypeError: $navigation.find(...).tab is not a function

$navigation.find('a:first').tab('show');
```

This is my application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require jquery.min
//= require toastr
//= require owl.carousel.min
//= require parsley.min
//= require jquery.bootstrap.wizard
//= require jquery.validate.min
//= require paper-bootstrap-wizard
//= require home
```

Comment: Possibly, you are missing js plugin for tabbing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sneaky problem. It is because `$navigation` (or whatever you want to select via the `.find()`) isn't a valid jquery object. Does it exist?
The reason you get that error is not because the plugin doesn't exist, but because the element doesn't and the plugin tries to 'tab' it.

```
// This will likely give the same error:
$("#nonExistingElement").tab{ /*... */}
```

If you want to check if your file is being loaded, add a simple `alert('test');` to the beginning of the plugin file. If it alerts, its loaded.

---

*While you are responsible for your own code, it is a bit sloppy from the plugin builder not to have a simple check for this.*

Comment: Thanks Mr Martijn, the js file was override by js.min file because of that am getting this issue. Thanks for your support and help.